# Implement onkeyup() function in Zend forms to add an element

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

I want to implement a sort of `onkeyup()` function  in Zend form to add an element. I don't know the syntax.

This is my code:

```
$this->addElement('text', 'userid', array(
    'label'      => '',
    'required'   => true,
    'filters'    => array('StringTrim'),
    'style'    => array('width:212px'),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code:

```
$this->addElement('text', 'userid', array(
    'label'      => '',
    'required'   => true,
    'filters'    => array('StringTrim'),
    'style'    => array('width:212px'),
    'attribs'    => array('onkeyup'=>'jsFunction();')
));
```

OR you can use below code:

```
$element = $this->addElement('text', 'userid', array(
        'label'      => '',
        'required'   => true,
        'filters'    => array('StringTrim'),
        'style'    => array('width:212px'),
    ));

$element->setAttrib('onkeyup', 'jsFunction();');
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to use `attribs` options to add extra attributes

Try This

```
$this->addElement('text', 'userid', array(
'label'      => '',
'required'   => true,
'filters'    => array('StringTrim'),
'style'      => array('width:212px'),  
'attribs' => array('onkeyup'=>'handler()')
```

you can also use [setAttrib](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.form.elements.html#zend.form.elements.metadata)

Comment: @Delta whats the error .. can u see onkey attribute added to element ?